# parallel insert, update, delete with Entity Framework 4.3.1

Tags: entity-framework, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

Is it possible to insert, update, delete 1,000 distinct table rows in parallel by use of Entity Framework 4.3.1?

How would you go about? Parallel Framework Task? Threads? Something else?

Comment: since dbContext is not threadsafe , i would create a pool of them and run jobs on the pool. Rest depends on your database, transaction levels and tables involved ....

Answer (score 0):

You can use TPL to do this but I doubt with EF. With ADO.NET you would want to make sure the CommandText is unique for each call if that call would be made to the same row (updates most likely). So for that you may need to create a new connection per update and close it. Using Connection pool would only make sense for select queries as you don;t want a different thread to be making updates to the same table when some other thread is doing the same. Inserts may not be an issue. I don't see how deletes would be either. If a row is already deleted nothing will happen unless you're returning something and using it.

Or what you could do is copy items to collections (for updates delete existing ones) and then do bulk inserts.

You'll have to test to find out!